# What is the value of $5 * 6$ in the following patttern?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Mr. Pascal built a computer for multiplying numbers and named it "Ramanujan". But Ramanujan multiplies $(3, 5), (2, 4), (3, 4)$ and $(4, 7)$and results are $17, 10, 14$ and $34$. If Ramanujan multiplies $(5, 6)$, what will be the result?

**Source: Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2015 Junior Category**

I can not get the pattern. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: How about
$$
(a,b) = a\times b + 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
2& \text{ if } b-a<3\\
4& \text{ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
:D

Comment: You have been posting a lot of questions from the Bangladesh Math Olympiad recently, and to be frank, they haven't been [very good question posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and they would be better if you [added some of your thoughts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Also, isn't there an official solution somewhere?

Comment: @Arthur I am taking your advice positively and there are no official solutions of this problems.

Comment: @MattiP. $4\times7+4\ne34$

Comment: Note that Pascal lived two centuries before Ramanujan. What a great anticipator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (as requested): Think about other bases!

Though I'll remark that I dislike these types of problems, *especially* in competition mathematics, since you can describe any suitable formulation and use it to justify practically any answer - as evidenced by Matti P's comment.